# How to get a realtime Histogram of a live video feed using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, qt5, ubuntu-16.04, histogram

I'm trying to get a real-time histogram from video feed from my webcam. But I'm stuck at a point where only the first frame of the video is captured and it's equivalent histogram is shown. Also, I'm using OpenCV2 in Qt Creator.  Here is the code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);

 /// Capture video
VideoCapture cap(0);
 if( cap.isOpened() == false )
   { exit(0); }

 while(true)
 {
    Mat frame;
    bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame);
    if (bSuccess == false)
      {
        ui->label->setText("Video camera is disconnected");
        exit(0);
      }

    /// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
    vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
    split(frame, bgr_planes );

    /// Establish the number of bins
     int histSize = 256;

    /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
    float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
    const float* histRange = { range };

     bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

     Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;

     /// Compute the histograms:
     calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
     calcHist( &bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
     calcHist( &bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );

    // Draw the histograms for B, G and R
    int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
    int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize );

    Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );

    /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ]
    normalize(b_hist, b_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
    normalize(g_hist, g_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
    normalize(r_hist, r_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

     /// Draw for each channel
    for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
    {
        line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                      Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                      Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
        line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                      Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                      Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
        line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                      Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                      Scalar( 0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0  );
    }

    /// Display
    namedWindow("calcHist Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("calcHist Demo", histImage );
    namedWindow("Video Capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Video Capture", frame );

    waitKey(0);

    exit(0);

 }

   }

 MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
     delete ui;
}
```

[image: This image] shows the output of my code. Can anyone suggest me how should I proceed on this code so as to achieve a real-time histogram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your capture loop you are using `waitKey(0)` which is a OpenCV function that waits for a key press. The integer parameter indicates how long (in milliseconds) the function waits for a key press. A value of 0 means to wait until a key press happens. This is why your program stops after the first frame. You would have to hit any key to observe the next frame (after also removing `exit(0)` which terminates the program).

If you want to see a video stream you can use a smaller value, e.g., 10 for waiting only 10 ms allowing for a framerate of upto 100 FPS.

Also you should remove the `exit` function since this function will terminate your program after the `waitKey` function is done waiting for a key press.

As a side note: the `waitKey` function also returns a number indicating which key was pressed. You could use this to trigger different behaviors of your program, e.g., terminating your program.

Answer (score 0):

You have `waitKey(0)` and `exit(0)` in your `while(true)` loop. Without looking into the source of `waitKey`, I can make the following guess: You get the histogram once, then you press a button, then it exits.

I suspect that if you take the `waitKey` and `exit` calls out of your program, you'll get what you want.